# Missing properties in instance of class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, reflection

I'm writing generic method in Android app, and I have a problem with missing properties.
My class has 7 public properties but when I'm trying to get all properties I'm getting list with one property. 
Here is my code:

```
T item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Problem occurs in all classes.
I have the same code (also the same classes) in similar application for iOS and everything works fine.

Here is sample class:

```
public partial class DB_USER {

        private int iD_USERField;

        private int iD_ACTORField;

        private System.Nullable<long> iD_DISTRIBUTORField;

        private string lOGINField;

        private string pASSWORDField;

        private bool iS_BLOCKEDField;

        private string dESCRIPTIONField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public int ID_USER {
            get {
                return this.iD_OPERATORField;
            }
            set {
                this.iD_OPERATORField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public int ID_ACTOR {
            get {
                return this.iD_ACTORField;
            }
            set {
                this.iD_ACTORField = value;
            }
        }

          /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public System.Nullable<long> ID_DISTRIBUTOR {
            get {
                return this.iD_DISTRIBUTORField;
            }
            set {
                this.iD_DISTRIBUTORField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string LOGIN {
            get {
                return this.lOGINField;
            }
            set {
                this.lOGINField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PASSWORD {
            get {
                return this.pASSWORDField;
            }
            set {
                this.pASSWORDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public bool IS_BLOCKED {
            get {
                return this.iS_BLOCKEDField;
            }
            set {
                this.iS_BLOCKEDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string DESCRIPTION {
            get {
                return this.dESCRIPTIONField;
            }
            set {
                this.dESCRIPTIONField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this: `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)`

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: try GetRuntimeProperties()

Comment: You can also use `typeof(T).GetProperties()` if you dont need the instance. What does the class with the properties look like? Are the properties really public?

Comment: Yes, properties is public but I just saw that on this list I can see only nullable properties. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: typeof(T).GetProperties() also returned list with one property

Comment: Can you post the class which you want to get the properties from?

Comment: If I use `var props = typeof(DB_USER).GetProperties();` I get 7 properties. Do you use the correct class? Do you use an interface?

Comment: I know. As I said, on iOS application everything works fine. Problem occurs only in Android project.